# Why is it writing strange symbols into the file in binary using the write function and not the intergers?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have an array of 20 numbers. I'm trying to add each number into the array, but I'm doing it in binary. The reason I'm doing it in binary is because I'm trying to get ready for my exam tomorrow. This is the code I have.

```
file.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary);
for (int number = 0, index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
    number = numbers[index];
    if (!file.eof()) {
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&number), sizeof(number));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

**The output of the text file is:"  $1@Qdyê©ƒ·!Di"**

Why? I know the array is populated because I've used a cout statement to see what in it. I also know that the variable used to get the number works because I've used a cout to see if it was getting the value from the array correctly.

Comment: Because the thing you're writing is not text, so when interpreted as text it looks like garbage?

Comment: how are numbers not text? Am I not allowed to write integers into a text file in binary mode?

Comment: Are you thinking `reinterpret_cast` converts int to text? because it doesn't. And an `int` is a binary value, not a sequence of characters. So you're writing that binary data.

Comment: Well, I was taught that that's what you need to do to write into the file. I didn't know that it can only write letters like that and not numbers. If I use letters, they show fine. if I do integers, it returns garbage.

Comment: Have you studied low-level representation of types in memory? When you use `reinterpret_cast`, that's what you're dealing with - the results tend to be platform-defined. Integers aren't encoded as text in memory because text (sequences of character codes, each character code itself being a number) is an inefficient and awkward representation to implement arithmetic operations on. Using [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) as the character coding, the digit `0` is encoded as the number 48. As a single byte can only distinguish 256 values (0 to 255), integers are encoded as several bytes.

Comment: Well I was told in my class that reinterpret_cast was used to work with non-character values so I thought it meant that we use reinterpret cast to put non-character values into binary files. Which I'm sure worked, but now that I'm trying to read from it, it crashes.

Comment: @JozemiteApps "Now that I'm trying to read from it, it crashes" - that sounds like a separate problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write integers into a file in binary mode, you should be reading them back in binary mode as well. Text editors cannot do that.

Moreover, the data would be written in a system-specific way, i.e. either the least significant or the most significant byte first. Text editors re-interpret these numbers as characters, so you see "garbage" output.

Checking for `eof()` is not necessary when you *write* the file, so you can drop it from your code.

```
file.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary);
for (int number = 0, index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
    number = numbers[index];
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&number), sizeof(number));
}
```

To make sure that you wrote the right data, write a small program that reads from the file in binary mode, and prints numbers as integers. You will see the numbers from the `numbers[]` array.

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "binary mode" since the issue is doing formatted output versus writing a byte array, not opening a file in binary mode versus text mode.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to read from it but it keeps crashing. It crashes on the .read line. It says: "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::ios_base::failure: ios_base::clear: unspecified iostream_category error". I have the same setup used in other examples I've found on google. I have it reopened as file.open(fileName, ios::in | ios::binary)

Comment: @JozemiteApps Did you get it to work? Try this from a different program. You should be able to read the whole array in with a single call to `read`, passing the 20-element array and its `sizeof`.